# No menu choice for Windows after installing Ubuntu 19, but it works

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, 19.04

I have Windows 10 and 7 together, with dual boot, then I installed Ubuntu 19. Everything was working just fine. First screen I could choose either Ubuntu or Windows. If I selected Windows, then it showed another original Windows selection 10 or 7. but now, just few reboots, the second menu choice (W10 or W7) disapeared with some fancy lines and colors, and after few seconds, it boots up in Windows. I believe after first Ubuntu upgrade this issue started. Looks like old video-card issue, but I have Lenovo ThinkPad X240 - Intel i5 with 8GB ram. I can't find a solution over the internet. I see a lot people complainig missing choise menu, but looks like a diffrent issue. It works but I just can't see the menu.

Comment: One possibility would be that the Ubuntu loader overwrote the MS-Windows loader... I don't see why it would not have happened the first time, though.

Comment: Since the problem seems to appear in the Windows boot-manager, it is a Windows problem. I also don't see a reason why an Ubuntu upgrade should damage the Windows boot-manager. I'd recommend to ask this question at https://superuser.com/